# How to open Firefox in Kiosk mode with only keep back button?

Tags: firefox, customization, kiosk

I want the user only can use browser and don't he leaves the browser after Ubuntu boot, so I choose kiosk mode.
But there is no back button in kiosk mode.
How can I keep back button in kiosk mode.
Or is there any way to customize the firefox to reach this goal.